# Show and hide div based on selected radio input

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have a div that I want to show if the user makes a selection in a radio button.
I am using bootstrap. Can you help me with doing that? I've tried with select inputs but I cannot with my radio buttons.

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function on_change(el){
        if(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value == 'optradio1'){ 
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block'; // Show el
        }else{
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none'; // Hide el
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <h1>Hello, world!</h1> -->
<div class="container" "row justify-content-md-center">
<h4>Please Choose a Table Below</h4>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1" onchange='on_change(this)'>MDM_Sls_Rep_Dim_Na</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Sample_Table1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio disabled">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Sample_Table2</label>
</div>
</div>
<!-- <div class="radio"> -->
<!-- <select id="mySelect" onchange='on_change(this)'> // Note the onchange event handler, which passes the select object to the on_change function via the 'this' variable -->
    <!-- <option value='one'>One</option> // Note I added value='one' -->
    <!-- <option value='two'>Two</option> // Note I added value='two' -->
<!-- </select> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<div id="text" style="display:none;"> // Note display:none instead of display:hidden
    The text would show if the user chooses option "Two"
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to keep in mind when you're doing this. First of all, you're not using the inputs properly.

The name of all 3 inputs should be the same if they're a group, and then you change the value. Like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" oninput='on_change(event)' value="sample1">
```

Also, note that instead of passing `this` as a parameter, I'm passing the `event`. `this` will provide the DOM element, the event will provide more info, and that will include the value you selected.

Finally, you need to modify the function to work with this:

```
function on_change(el){
      var selectedOption = el.target.value;
      if (selectedOption === 'MDM') {
        document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none'; // Hide el
      }

    }
```

The snippet below shows how this works all together.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function on_change(el){
      var selectedOption = el.target.value;
      if (selectedOption === 'MDM') {
        document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none'; // Hide el
      }
      
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <h1>Hello, world!</h1> -->
<div class="container" "row justify-content-md-center">
<h4>Please Choose a Table Below</h4>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" oninput='on_change(event)' value="MDM">MDM_Sls_Rep_Dim_Na</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" oninput='on_change(event)' value="sample1">Sample_Table1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio disabled">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" oninput='on_change(event)'  value="sample2">Sample_Table2</label>
</div>
</div>
<!-- <div class="radio"> -->
<!-- <select id="mySelect" onchange='on_change(this)'> // Note the onchange event handler, which passes the select object to the on_change function via the 'this' variable -->
    <!-- <option value='one'>One</option> // Note I added value='one' -->
    <!-- <option value='two'>Two</option> // Note I added value='two' -->
<!-- </select> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<div id="text" style="display:none;"> // Note display:none instead of display:hidden
    The text would show if the user chooses option "Two"
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran this code and nothing is happening when I select one of the radio buttons

Comment: @dmoses, the first radio button will show an additional div, and the other ones will hide it.

Comment: How can I uncheck the other inputs once the radio button with the onchange event is selected? I would like only one radio button to be selected at a time.

Comment: it does not seem to work well in IE have you tried it?

Comment: If you give all 3 inputs the *same name*, but different values, you will only be able to check one at a time.

Comment: If you select show code snippet -> run code snippet-> full page in Internet Explorer it does not work.

Comment: I got it just needed to update the javascript see my post below.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the `name` attribute from `selected`

```js
function on_change(el){
        if(el.name == 'optradio1'){ 
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block'; // Show el
        }else{
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none'; // Hide el
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<div class="container" "row justify-content-md-center">
<h4>Please Choose a Table Below</h4>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1" onchange="on_change(this)">MDM_Sls_Rep_Dim_Na</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" onchange="on_change(this)">Sample_Table1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio disabled">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" onchange="on_change(this)">Sample_Table2</label>
</div>
</div>
<div id="text" style="display:none;color:red"> // Note display:none instead of display:hidden
    The text would show if the user chooses option "Two"
</div>
```

Comment: I ran this code and nothing is happening when I select one of the radio buttons

Comment: dont you see the text that show/hide try run code snippet

Comment: I set color red that you see

Comment: if you want to click to remove radio you have to call all of them in same `name`

Comment: The snippet works but when I try to run this code in IE or Firefox I get nothing

Comment: How can I uncheck the other inputs once the radio button with the onchange event is selected? I would like only one radio button to be selected at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This version works on IE and Chrome. Simply just updated the el.name in the script to el.value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-3">
  <h2>Please Choose a Table Below</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1" onchange="on_change(this)" value="MDM">MDM_Sls_Rep_Dim_Na</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1" onchange="on_change(this)">Sample_Table1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1" onchange="on_change(this)">Sample_Table2</label>
    </div>
  </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-3">
<div id="text" style="display:none;color:red">
<br><br><br>
// Note MDM_Sls_Rep_Dim_Na
 Rules: <br>
    1. Rep code must be five digits <br>
    2. Date format must be 'mm-dd-yyyy' <br>
    3. Rep Code exists in bi.t_sls_rep_dim_na


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-3">
     <h4>Please Choose a Table Below</h4>
<form>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1" onchange="on_change(this)">MDM_Sls_Rep_Dim_Na</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
<label><input type="radio" name="optradio2">Sample_Table1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio3">Sample_Table2</label>
</div>
 </form>   
</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-3">
<div id="text" style="display:none;color:red">
<br><br><br>
// Note MDM_Sls_Rep_Dim_Na
 Rules: <br>
    1. Rep code must be five digits <br>
    2. Date format must be 'mm-dd-yyyy' <br>
    3. Rep Code exists in bi.t_sls_rep_dim_na


        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function on_change(el){
        if(el.value == 'MDM'){ 
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block'; // Show el
        }else{
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none'; 
                    // Hide el
        }






    }
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```